Why does it seem the letter خ is the only consonant that precedes an unpronounced و in Persian?
In Persian I know 10 letters that in them, خ precedes an unpronounced و:

خواب (khab) which means sleep.
خواجه (khajeh) which means eunuch.
خوار (khar) which means humiliated.
خوارَزم (kharazm) which is a historical geographical place.
خواستَن (khastan) which means to want.
خواف (khaf) which is a city in Iran.
خوالی (khali) which means food (Old Persian I think).
خوان (khan) which means tablecloth (a synonym is سُفره).
خواندَن (khandan) which means to read.
خواهَر (khahar) which means sister.

Of course there are also other words which are derivatives of خواستَن and خواندَن; but I avoided them (like خواهِش and خوانَنده)
خوار also has another meaning from Old Persian. It is related to خوردَن (khordan) which means to eat (We now have words like گیاهخوار (giahkhar) which means herbivore).
In all these words the letter و is mute.
I have searched for other words with different consonants, but I failed.
Why is the lertter خ the only one that has this feature?

I don’t know much (virtually nothing, in fact) about modern Persian, but based on the fact that at least some of these words go back to Old Iranian/Avestan words with initial /xʷ/, my guess would be that /xʷ/ simply lost its labialisation at some point during the history of Persian, but the glide continues to be written for historic reasons. It’s similar to how Germanic initial /w/ was borrowed into Old French as /gʷ/, which later lost its labialisation and merged with /g/, but guard and guarantee, which were taken via French, are still written with ⟨gu⟩.

@JanusBahsJacquet Were there also other consonants that connected to a w in Old Persian? For example, sʷ, etc.

Not as far as I can recall, no. Iranian is a branch of Indo-Iranian, which is satem, meaning that the original Indo-European labialised consonants *kʷ, *gʷ and *gʷʰ  had all lost their labialisation and merged with plain *k, *g_ and *gʰ (the latter two also merging as *g). Apart from those, Proto-Indo-European could have *u̯ (= /w/) after most consonants, as could Old Iranian, but I think *su̯ is the only one that developed into a single morpheme in Iranian.

@JanusBahsJacquet What's the example for gʷʰ and g_?

For *gʷʰ, there’s PIE *gʷʰor-mós ‘warm(th)’ > Proto-Indo-Iranian *gʰarmás > Proto-Iranian *garmáh > Avestan  garəma. Plain *g is trickier, since that’s a rarer sound in PIE. Wiktionary has a PI *gáwbati ‘say’, which is possibly from PIE *geu̯H-; this lemma doesn’t seem to be attested in Avestan, but it’s the ancestor of Persian گفتن guftan.

The Indo-European and Indo-Iranian cluster *sw- becomes *hw- or *xw- in proto-Iranian. The  latter remains in Middle Persian and Early New Persian. It is retained in the Arabo-Persian script, but is reduced to x- in most forms of Modern Persian.
